# Shared Preferences are being created but value being stored for the key is 0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I am working on an app for my self which is taking the value and storing it in a shared preferences , the shared preferences is being created but the value for that key is stored as 0. Here's the main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int totalcount;
EditText etCount;
Button submit,cont;
String []hours={"8:30 - 9:30","9:30 - 10:30","10:30 - 11:30","11:30 - 12:30","12:30 - 1:30","1:30 - 2:30","2:30 - 3:30","3:30 - 4:30","4:30 - 5:30"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    etCount= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    submit =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    cont =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    try{
    totalcount= Integer.parseInt(etCount.getText().toString());
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        nfe.printStackTrace();

    }
    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SharedPreferences sp= getSharedPreferences("Count", MODE_APPEND);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit= sp.edit();
            edit.putInt("totalcount", totalcount);
            edit.commit();

                Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.youtubehourlycounter.HourlyCountKeeper.class);
                startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    cont.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.youtubehourlycounter.HourlyCountKeeper.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    }
```

and here's the next activity where am trying to retrieve it.

```
public class HourlyCountKeeper extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hourly_count_keeper);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    String []hours={"8:30 - 9:30","9:30 - 10:30","10:30 - 11:30","11:30 - 12:30","12:30 - 1:30","1:30 - 2:30","2:30 - 3:30","3:30 - 4:30","4:30 - 5:30"};
    SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("Count", MODE_APPEND);
    int str= sp.getInt("totalcount", 1000);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String,HourlyData>> al = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,HourlyData>>();  
    for(int i=0;i<=8;i++){
    HashMap<String, HourlyData> hm= new HashMap<String, HourlyData>();

    HourlyData hd= new HourlyData();
    hd.hours=hours[i].toString();

    SharedPreferences sp1=getSharedPreferences("CurrentCountFor"+hours[i], MODE_APPEND);
    int ccf= sp1.getInt("CurrentCountFor"+hours[i], 0);

    int thishourscount=str/9;

    hd.TargetByRemaining= (ccf+"/"+thishourscount).toString();

    if(ccf==thishourscount){
        hd.done=1;

    }else{
        hd.done=0;
    }

    hm.put("HourlyData", hd);

    al.add(hm);
    MyAdapter adapter= new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),al);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

When i check in the file manager, inside the app --> shared preferences folder, i find the files, on pulling them the data which is inside the count is something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<int name="count" value="0" />
</map>
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following code inside your `onClickListener` for  **submit** button-

```
try{
totalcount= Integer.parseInt(etCount.getText().toString());
}catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
    nfe.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: It works, why would it work inside an OnClickListener but not outside it?

Comment: Before, your code was only inside `onCreate` so whenever the `Activity` was created immediately the `EditText` value was retrieved and assigned to `totalcount`. At that time your `EditText` contains null that's why the value stored was 0. Now, it is inside the `onClickListener`, so the `EditText` value is retrieved when the button is clicked and at that time the value is not null.